# Seeding users and roles in dbcontext in asp.net core: Circular dependency problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I am injecting `UserManager` and `RoleManager` in the dbcontext file to use them for adding some users and roles when the database is first created. When I run the `update-database` command, I receive the following error:

> A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'App.Models.AppDbContext'.
>   App.Models.AppDbContext -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore

Below is the `dbcontext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

    public AppDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<SynergyDbContext> options,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
        ) : base(options) {

        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() });

     ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
     {
         //implementation details
     };

     IdentityResult result = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password").Result;
     if (result.Succeeded) _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
 }
```

Any ideas? Should I create the users with `HasData` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `AppDbContext` is injected with dependency `UserManager` which is injected with dependency `UserStore` which is needed to be injected with dependency `DbContext`. Therefore you get circular dependency problem.

Solution is to create your users outside of `DbContext`, so you don't inject those services into `DbContext`.